# Set Print Scaling in PDF metadata using Node-Exiftool

Tags: node.js, pdf, metadata, exiftool

I'm trying to use [Node-exiftool](https://github.com/Sobesednik/node-exiftool) to set the Print dialog Print-Scaling metadata to None.

[image]

I don't know how to format the data object to achieve this result, I'm not even sure if it's possible, something like this maybe?:

```
  ep.writeMetadata(pdfOutput, {
    'Keywords+': [ 'No-Scale', 'PDF' ],
    'Type': {
      'Catalog': {
        'ViewerPreferences' : [
          {
            'PrintScaling': 'None'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }, ['overwrite_original']);
```

This is the pdf metadata result I need:

```
12 0 obj
<</AcroForm 27 0 R/Metadata 2 0 R/Pages 9 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences<</PrintScaling/None>>>>
endobj
```

If there's a better tool to do this, I'm all ears too.